# Intermittent internet connection with Ethernet, Realtek 8111/8168/8411, works fine on windows / Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

I have a ASUS Zephyrus M15 GU502LW with both Ubuntu 21.10 and Windows 10.

While on Ubuntu I regularly lose connection to the internet. Pings to google and my router fail at the same time, for around 3 packages, every minute or more if the connection is actively being used by a browser or cmd tool.

I checked and there is no static IP set in my device or router, so I don't suspect a DHCP issue. I'm wired straight to my ISP router (a sagecom FAST3686) and this doesen't happen with Windows or on WiFi, so I assume It's driver related

I don't know how to approach this. I found a lot of other posts of people with this issue, but they fixed it by installing r8168 drivers, which say they are only for kernels up to 5.6, and I'm running a newer version.

```
~ $ sudo lshw -c network                                                                                                                                    (base) 
  *-network DESACTIVADO     
       descripción: Interfaz inalámbrica
       producto: Comet Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       id físico: 14.3
       información del bus: pci@0000:00:14.3
       nombre lógico: wlo1
       versión: 00
       serie: 3c:9c:0f:f6:c1:a1
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuración: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.13.0-39-generic firmware=63.c04f3485.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-63.u latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       recursos: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memoria:6044018000-604401bfff
  *-network
       descripción: Ethernet interface
       producto: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:3d:00.0
       nombre lógico: eno2
       versión: 15
       serie: f0:2f:74:46:0c:0d
       tamaño: 100Mbit/s
       capacidad: 1Gbit/s
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuración: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.13.0-39-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.0.3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       recursos: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memoria:98204000-98204fff memoria:98200000-98203fff

~ $ ifconfig                                                                                                                                                (base) 
eno2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        ether f0:2f:74:46:0c:0d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2180471  bytes 2729748335 (2.7 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 772  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 315405  bytes 32702503 (32.7 MB)
        TX errors 3  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Bucle local)
        RX packets 58739  bytes 6195440 (6.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 58739  bytes 6195440 (6.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

~ $ lspci
3d:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
~ $ uname --all                                                                                                                
Linux Mauro-Linux 5.13.0-39-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 24 15:35:05 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Does your router have 1G LAN ports? If so, your connection speed suggests a bad ethernet cable. Are you using cat 5e or cat 6 cables? There are two other steps that we can take, but let's eliminate the cable issue first.

Comment: I assume the cable is fine, since It's cat 6 and I don't have the same issue on Windows. I'll change it just in case, but I'm certain that's not the issue.

Comment: The fact that it works with Windows means nothing, as you're using Linux, and they just do things differently. Let me know if the link speed becomes 1G after the cable change.

Comment: Well I have to eat my words because as soon as I plugged the new cable it went to 1gb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

```
   tamaño: 100Mbit/s
   capacidad: 1Gbit/s
```

Because the link speed was only 100Mbit/s I suspected a cable problem. We changed out the cable and the link speed became 1Gbit/s as expected.